# Cannot insert integer into multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have some code sorta like this:

```
vector< vector<int> > vec; // multidimensional vector
while (condition)
{
    vec.push_back(vector<int>()); // add subvectors to vec
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        vec[vec.size()].push_back(i); // add integers to those subvectors (the problem)
    }
}
```

I am using `vec[vec.size()]` to get the last element within my main vector to insert an integer into it. I do not understand why this is, but I get all kinds of errors from this code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `vec[vec.size()]` = recipe for undefined behavior. And Fyi, it would make considerably more sense to fill a vector, *then* push it into the outer vector as the *last* thing before the next iteration of the while-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know that indexing in C/C++ is from [0,size-1] thus to insert integers into the last vector in your vector of vectors use the following code

```
vec[vec.size()-1].push_back(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

A more common way is to do it as follows:

```
vector< vector<int> > vec; // multidimensional vector
vector<int> a;
// push back elements to a
vec.push_back(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody mention it, you can do:

```
vec[x][y] = 5;
```

It will work as one my expect.

But I personally found "Eissa N." solution better.

Comment: Just to comment that `vec[x][y] = 5;` requires resizing vector in both dimensions first.

Comment: if I know the dimensions, I would go with your solution + `vec.reserve()`